# Jquery-code optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I only need to have different marginLeft values of the animate() inside the else if blocks and everything other in the else if blocks should be the same. The script is as follows :

```
 var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
        function(){
        if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 0) {
            imgElement.animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginTop: "-50px",
                marginLeft: "-150px",
            }, 1500 );
            imgElement.css("z-index","100");
            imgElement.css("position","absolute");
            imgElement.css("opacity","1");
            }
        else if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
                     //The same thing but marginLeft: "-200px"
            }
         }, 1500);
```

Comment: 6 viable answers within 6 minutes of posting - you are spoiled for choice!

Comment: Unrelated: you can replace the multiple calls to `css('property', 'value')` with a single `css({'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'})` call.

Comment: @Radu - it's related--the topic is on jQuery optimization. I even included it in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull your object out into a var:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
    function(){
        var animateArgs = {
            width: "315px",
            height: "225px",
            marginTop: "-50px",
            marginLeft: "-150px",
        };
        if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 0) {
            imgElement.animate(animateArgs, 1500 );
            imgElement.css("z-index","100");
            imgElement.css("position","absolute");
            imgElement.css("opacity","1");
        }
        else if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
            animateArgs.marginLeft = "-200px";
            // etc etc etc
        }
    }, 
    1500
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the value in a variable, set the variable's value according to your conditions, then use the variable instead of the hardcoded value.

```
var marginLeft = "-150px"; // extract the default value in a variable
if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
    marginLeft = "-200px"; // change the value according to conditions
}
imgElement.animate({
    width: "315px",
    height: "225px",
    marginTop: "-50px",
    marginLeft: marginLeft, // use the value from the variable
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var settings = {
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginTop: "-50px",
            };
var css = { // the CSS };

if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 0) {
    settings.marginLeft = "-150px";
} else if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
    settings.marginLeft = "-200px";
}
imgElement.animate(settings, 1500)
          .css(css);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
        function(){
        // same for both index == 0 and index == 1
        if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 0 || imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
            imgElement.animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginTop: "-50px",
                // if index == 1 then -200 (px is assumed) else -150
                marginLeft: imgs.index(imgElement) ? -200 : -150,
            }, 1500 );
            imgElement.css("z-index","100");
            imgElement.css("position","absolute");
            imgElement.css("opacity","1");
            }
         }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
        function(){
            imgElement.animate({
                width: "315px",
                height: "225px",
                marginTop: "-50px",
                marginLeft: imgs.index(imgElement)?"-150px":"-200px",
            }, 1500 );
            imgElement.css("z-index","100");
            imgElement.css("position","absolute");
            imgElement.css("opacity","1");
         }, 1500);
```

Comment: this is like my answer, but assumes that if statement is not necessary. There might however be other values for the index that do not need this animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(
function(){
    var parms = {
            width: "315px",
            height: "225px",
            marginTop: "-50px"
        };
    if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 0) {
        parms.marginLeft: "-150px";
    }
    else if (imgs.index(imgElement) == 1) {
        parms.marginLeft: "-200px";
    }
    imgElement.animate(parms, 1500);
    imgElement.css("z-index","100");
    imgElement.css("position","absolute");
    imgElement.css("opacity","1");
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up the options, modify as necessary, then use it.  Also, combine your `.css()` calls to lessen the number of API calls you make.

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout( function()
{
    var animateOptions = {
        width: '315px',
        height: '225px',
        marginTop: '-50px'
    };

    if( imgs.index( imgElement ) === 0)
    {
        animateOptions.marginLeft = '-150px'
    }
    else if( imgs.index( imgElement ) === 1 )
    {
        animateOptions.marginLeft = '-200px'
    }
    else
    {
        // you should probably do something if neither condition is met
        // or set a default for the value in the initial setup
    }

    imgElement
        .animate( animateOptions, 1500 )
        .css( {
            zIndex: 100,
            position: 'absolute',
            opacity: 1
        } );
}, 1500 );
```